# Does "first day/time-slot" refer to Monday and not Friday?

Tags: meaning, time

I've had my professor's text, as follows:

> Select which you would like to come to: the first (= Class A) or second (= Class B) day/time-slot available on your weekly schedule.

Here is the question. I have two classes per week. (Mon & Fri) I will have my first class ever next Friday. But in a week, Monday comes before Friday right?

Can anyone tell me your thoughts? Class A is Monday or Friday?

Comment: It's not easy to answer this (my inclination would be that Monday is the first slot and Friday the second, regardless of what happens in the first week). To be unambiguous, you could reply explicitly with the day/time you wish to attend (unless it is some kind of automated system).

Comment: Thanks ! Yes it is a automated system and I don't know who are my professer yet.

Comment: 'A' is a label arbitrarily assigned.

Comment: Thanks Mr Edwin. Agree with you.

Comment: Class A and Class B times are when you *cannot* attend, because they are taking up time slots on your schedule; those times are not available. It sounds like they are trying to schedule a meeting (or something) that does not conflict with your schedule.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering is relative to “your weekly schedule”. This provides the context for disambiguation.

You haven’t provided your weekly schedule, but it will likely have days of the week across the top.

If the first column says Sunday, then Sunday comes before the other days of the week in your quote.

If the first column says Friday (which is not common in my experience), then the Friday class has priority.

If you don’t have such a schedule, the ambiguity is not resolved.

Comment: Thanks ! Helps a lot.